# SQL Server Deadlock

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I am running SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1 + Non Security Update (KB2793634). I am frequently getting deadlocks occur, 99% of the time with the same 2 queries. How can i prevent this deadlock from happening ?

Here is the deadlock details :

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process578a88188">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process578a88188" taskpriority="0" logused="2036" waitresource="KEY: 6:72057594089963520 (6533c2597184)" waittime="2954" ownerId="28095456501" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2016-07-20T13:30:16.490" XDES="0x38670a6c8" lockMode="X" schedulerid="3" kpid="5536" status="suspended" spid="124" sbid="1" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2016-07-20T13:30:16.627" lastbatchcompleted="2016-07-20T13:30:16.610" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.610" clientapp="PHP" hostname="WL-DC-A-QUEUE01" hostpid="3208" loginname="simpro" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="28095456501" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="52" sqlhandle="0x02000000c1ad4b2a727cb2c9f7ba407e398d53c0824708850000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE workflow_request SET updated = @P1 WHERE id = @P2     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@P1 nvarchar(26),@P2 int)UPDATE workflow_request SET updated = @P1 WHERE id = @P2    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process61e0a9868" taskpriority="0" logused="8484" waitresource="KEY: 6:72057594089963520 (49806bcce5bc)" waittime="3032" ownerId="28095456347" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2016-07-20T13:30:16.407" XDES="0x46e5c03a8" lockMode="U" schedulerid="4" kpid="5896" status="suspended" spid="91" sbid="1" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2016-07-20T13:30:16.550" lastbatchcompleted="2016-07-20T13:30:16.547" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.547" clientapp="PHP" hostname="WL-DC-A-QUEUE01" hostpid="2664" loginname="simpro" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="28095456347" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="108" sqlhandle="0x0200000029bc6522620287ccc7de73b3135f3b2e2fc578260000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE workflow_request SET current_state_id = @P1, status_id = @P2, updated_by_id = @P3, updated = @P4 WHERE id = @P5     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@P1 char(1),@P2 int,@P3 int,@P4 nvarchar(26),@P5 int)UPDATE workflow_request SET current_state_id = @P1, status_id = @P2, updated_by_id = @P3, updated = @P4 WHERE id = @P5    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594089963520" dbid="6" objectname="simprov4.dbo.workflow_request" indexname="PK__workflow__3213E83F498EEC8D" id="lock1474033780" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594089963520">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process61e0a9868" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process578a88188" mode="X" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594089963520" dbid="6" objectname="simprov4.dbo.workflow_request" indexname="PK__workflow__3213E83F498EEC8D" id="lock4e91ab400" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594089963520">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process578a88188" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process61e0a9868" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

Here is the table create statement :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [requester_id] [int] NULL,
    [sim_id] [int] NULL,
    [action_id] [int] NULL,
    [activate_data_id] [int] NULL,
    [cancel_data_id] [int] NULL,
    [allocate_ip_data_id] [int] NULL,
    [transition_id] [int] NULL,
    [current_state_id] [int] NULL,
    [status_id] [int] NULL,
    [locked_by_id] [int] NULL,
    [customer_request_batch_id] [int] NULL,
    [batch_id] [int] NULL,
    [skip] [bit] NULL,
    [network_reference] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [locked] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [last_result] [bit] NULL,
    [last_message] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [retry] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [retry_count] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [created] [datetime2](6) NOT NULL,
    [updated] [datetime2](6) NOT NULL,
    [sim_swap_data_id] [int] NULL,
    [enable_full_bar_data_id] [int] NULL,
    [disable_full_bar_data_id] [int] NULL,
    [edit_sims_data_id] [int] NULL,
    [enable_roaming_data_id] [int] NULL,
    [disable_roaming_data_id] [int] NULL,
    [sim_refresh_data_id] [int] NULL,
    [suspend_data_id] [int] NULL,
    [send_to_network] [bit] NULL,
    [spreference] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [updated_by_id] [int] NULL,
    [skip_creation_email] [bit] NULL,
    [skip_completion_email] [bit] NULL,
    [auto_complete] [bit] NULL,
    [send_to_customer] [bit] NULL,
    [manual_override] [bit] NULL,
    [ignore_failed_flag] [bit] NULL,
    [failed_status_id] [int] NULL,
    [email_to] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [delete_sims_data_id] [int] NULL,
    [undelete_sims_data_id] [int] NULL,
    [update_apn_data_id] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F161A0C43] FOREIGN KEY([customer_request_batch_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[workflow_customer_request_batch] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F161A0C43]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F4355328A] FOREIGN KEY([update_apn_data_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[workflow_update_apn_data] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F4355328A]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F44F7BE9D] FOREIGN KEY([suspend_data_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[workflow_suspend_data] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F44F7BE9D]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F4AA4DEB] FOREIGN KEY([sim_refresh_data_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[workflow_sim_refresh_data] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F4AA4DEB]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F4E0AB869] FOREIGN KEY([disable_roaming_data_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[workflow_disable_roaming_data] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F4E0AB869]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F5131BD6D] FOREIGN KEY([cancel_data_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[workflow_cancel_data] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F5131BD6D]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F54A7A1D9] FOREIGN KEY([allocate_ip_data_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[workflow_allocate_ip_data] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F54A7A1D9]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F575024C3] FOREIGN KEY([sim_swap_data_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[workflow_sim_swap_data] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F575024C3]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F5E711585] FOREIGN KEY([failed_status_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[workflow_request_failed_status] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F5E711585]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F6BF700BD] FOREIGN KEY([status_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[workflow_request_status] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F6BF700BD]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F7A88E00] FOREIGN KEY([locked_by_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[core_user] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F7A88E00]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F896DBBDE] FOREIGN KEY([updated_by_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[core_user] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F896DBBDE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F8BF1A064] FOREIGN KEY([transition_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[workflow_transition] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F8BF1A064]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F9527B049] FOREIGN KEY([enable_roaming_data_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[workflow_roaming_data] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F9527B049]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F97C93AED] FOREIGN KEY([enable_full_bar_data_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[workflow_enable_full_bar_data] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F97C93AED]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F98A046EB] FOREIGN KEY([current_state_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[workflow_state] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F98A046EB]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F9D32F035] FOREIGN KEY([action_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[workflow_action] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192F9D32F035]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192FAC7C372D] FOREIGN KEY([disable_full_bar_data_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[workflow_disable_full_bar_data] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192FAC7C372D]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192FC79087FC] FOREIGN KEY([activate_data_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[workflow_activate_data] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192FC79087FC]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192FE7793046] FOREIGN KEY([delete_sims_data_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[workflow_delete_sims_data] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192FE7793046]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192FED442CF4] FOREIGN KEY([requester_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[core_user] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192FED442CF4]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192FEF677A38] FOREIGN KEY([undelete_sims_data_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[workflow_undelete_sims_data] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192FEF677A38]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192FF81AF80C] FOREIGN KEY([sim_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[core_sim] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192FF81AF80C]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192FF94413E8] FOREIGN KEY([edit_sims_data_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[workflow_edit_sims_data] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[workflow_request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_39DB192FF94413E8]
GO
```

Execution plans for each query - [first query](https://gist.github.com/manseuk/18f4d1582be9e10f396f56f99690d7d2)  `UPDATE workflow_request SET updated = @P1 WHERE id = @P2` and [second query](https://gist.github.com/manseuk/5ff86ad9d5f4e75eb40b3689063a8274) `UPDATE workflow_request SET current_state_id = @P1, status_id = @P2, updated_by_id = @P3, updated = @P4 WHERE id = @P5`

[image: Full chart]
[image: Left Query]
[image: Right Query]

Comment: Is this your queries right? `UPDATE workflow_request SET updated = @P1 WHERE id = @P2 ` and `UPDATE workflow_request SET current_state_id = @P1, status_id = @P2, updated_by_id = @P3, updated = @P4 WHERE id = @P5`

Comment: @RafaelPiccinelli yep thats correct

Comment: Is this a Heap table? Do you have any index in this table?

Comment: @RafaelPiccinelli the table has an index (see the create statement above) - the primary key - do i need to add other indexes ?

Comment: What other statements run in the same transactions too?

Comment: @MartinSmith the transaction would also contain the same queries but to different records / rows

Comment: The conflict is over two rows on the same data page. Is there overlap in the ID values that the two queries are updating? Do you have an explicit transaction around both statements (i.e. `BEGIN TRAN...COMMIT`) that includes other updates to this table? This is essentially what MartinSmith asked, but I want to be very clear on this point. If yes, can you please post more of the entire batch, not just the queries getting the deadlock? You might need to experiment with table hints on the `UPDATE`s: `WITH (PAGLOCK)` or `WITH(ROWLOCK)`. Maybe start by adding `WITH (PAGLOCK)` to one of them.

Comment: @srutzky the other queries in the batch would update the same table but different records - im using an ORM (Doctrine) - and this means that the whole batch will be surrounded by a transaction. Im using Rabbitmq and i think the same rows are being updated by 2 processes - but why are they conflicting ? doesnt one complete then the next ?

Comment: @ManseUK - That may be the reason for the deadlock. Trn 1 updates Row 1 and the tries to update Row 2 by fetching exclusive lock on it. In the mean time Trn2 updates Row 2 and tries to update Row 1. now each transaction has an X lock on its respective rows and are trying to update the other transaction's row. hence the deadlock

Comment: @ManseUK Yes, the same rows being updated across both sessions conflict due to the explicit transaction. I see that you accepted an answer. Does this mean that the issue is resolved? I would be surprised if adding `WITH (ROWLOCK)` would help since that should be the cause of the problem, hence my suggesting to start with `PAGLOCK`. Of course removing the transaction entirely would prevent the deadlock, but that might be logically invalid for the operation being performed. And if you can't add a hint due to using an ORM, then there is another way, but it doesn't matter if this is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how any deadlock happens:

1. Transaction 1 (T1) starts. It locks some resources to work with, not all.
2. T1 does its job on first set and requests lock for the next set of resources. It does not release resources, because it happens only when T `COMMIT`s, usually when `T` ends.
3. T2 Requests locks some other available resources. T2 does not release locks until commit.
4. T2 requests resources locked by T1. It is waiting for T1 to finish and release resources.
5. Now T1 requests lock on resources already locked by T2. resources are locked, so T1 waits until T2 releases them.
6. Deadlock: T1 waiting for T2 while T2 waiting for T1. SQL Server kills one them. I would not be covering logic for this here.

Note: it applies to any resource the lock is applied to, not necessarily individual row.

Problem: Two Transactions need same resource over same period of time.

Options:
1. Change resource that's being locked. If lock is at page level and different rows on this page are needed, then `WITH (ROWLOCK)` should help. It will increase overheads of locking, but will allow different transactions to lock different rows on the same page.

2. Time period. If Transactions commit more frequently, time a row is locked reduced. It reduces chances for deadlocks, but does not prevent them from happening. There 2 main ways for this

   - Commit after each row update. Wrap `UPDATE` in a separate nested transaction. If each (sub-) transaction updates 1 row at a time, there will be no deadlocks. However it reduces performance, so need to be tested first.
   - Make each transaction shorter.

You may require more complex solution if logic of your transactions does not allow approaches above.

Comment: Thanks - great answer - easy to understand and some options - i will look at how i can get the application avoiding the situation of a deadlock occurring and go from there

Comment: If you share logic of your trans, you can get a solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the deadlock graph? As you are using SQL Server 2012, it should be available in the system_health extended events session.

This query was provided by Jonathan Kehayias in his pluralsight deadlock class.

```
SELECT 
    XEvent.query('data[@name="xml_report"]/value/deadlock') AS deadlock_graph
FROM    (SELECT CAST([target_data] AS XML) AS TargetData
         FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets AS st
         INNER JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions AS s 
            ON [s].[address] = [st].[event_session_address]
         WHERE [s].[name] = N'system_health'
           AND [st].[target_name] = N'ring_buffer') AS Data
CROSS APPLY TargetData.nodes ('RingBufferTarget/event[@name="xml_deadlock_report"]') AS XEventData (XEvent);
```

1. You then click on the corresponding deadlock graph
2. Save the xml result as an .xdl file
3. Then open it up in sql server management studio.

Once you've opened up the .xdl file in SSMS, hover your mouse over the ovals and you'll get the queries that participated in the deadlock.

This will provide you with additional information useful in resolving the deadlock.

Comment: The queries are logged above from the deadlock chart

Comment: @ManseUK, having a visual reference can be useful. At least for me it would.